# Redux infinite scroll loadmore not get triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux, infinite-scroll

I'm using redux infinite scroll https://github.com/RealScout/redux-infinite-scroll. The loadMore method is invoked only once, but on scrolling its not triggering the method.

```
        <div className="blog-list">
          <InfiniteScroll
            loadingMore={this.state.loadingMore}
            loadMore={this.loadMore}
          >
            {items}
          </InfiniteScroll>

        </div>

loadMore() {
 this.props.listPublicBlog(this.state.pageNumber, this.state.language);   
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No . I have added log on loadMore function , and I'm getting the log only once

Comment: Perhaps you need to bind this as in the docs example: `loadMore={this.loadMore.bind(this)}`